# MS Edge canvas doesn't honor SVG fill color

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, microsoft-edge

I have a webapp which has code to render a (monochrome) SVG to a canvas element via the `drawImage` function. The SVG is defined as having a white fill color, yet Edge will only render it in black. Does anyone know of a workaround for this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code was using a drop shadow for other parts of the canvas, and apparently Edge uses the wrong order for rendering and places the shadow in front of the SVG itself. This was a non-issue on other browsers, but on Edge it causes the image to appear entirely black.

Comment: where was your drop shadow?

Comment: @stackjlei The canvas had the `shadowBlur` property set, which applies a drop shadow to all elements drawn while it's active.